# What counters (PerfMon) to add to find performance issues in a C# WCF web service?

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, performancecounter, performance

I am looking into Performance issues of an Asp.Net 2.0 Web Site which uses a WCF service. On the Web and the WCF Host Service I am adding some Perf Counters to analyse the application behaviour. What are the Performance Counters which will be useful. I have created a partial list. Can someone suggest me if I am missing any important counter.

.Ner CLR Data : Peak Pooled Connections, Total # Failed Commands,Total # Failed Connects

.Net CLR Exceptions: Total # exceptions thrown,

.Net CLR Locks and Threads: Total # of Contentions

.Net Memory: # Bytes in all heap

.Net CLR Loading : Rate of class loaded

Asp.Net 2.0: Requests Current, State Server Sessions Active, State Server Sessions Total,
 Worker Process Restarts, Worker Process Running

Comment: You might want to edit the title of your question to include "c# WCF web service" or something, to draw more appropriate help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the various WCF counters?

Answer (score 2):

WCF provides its own [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx) for services.

Enable it on your services app.config using:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The most useful counters will be stuff like Calls Duration, Calls Outstanding, Calls Failed etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to monitor the number of garbage collections that occur, and the processor utilisation on the server

Answer (score 1):

If there is a SQL Server database, add `SQL Statistics / Batch Queries/sec`.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150701064526/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajay/archive/2009/09/14/wcf-performance-counters.aspx) about the handiest performance counters was available when the question was asked.

- PercentOfMaxCalls
- PercentOfMaxSessions
- PercentOfMaxInstances
- CallsOutstanding

Comment: The link no longer works, but thankfully there's the Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20150701064526/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajay/archive/2009/09/14/wcf-performance-counters.aspx

Comment: @KenPespisa: Thanks for that, I've updated the link. Microsoft have removed a lot of their old support and dev web content in the last few years. I wish they would recognize its importance and archive it themselves.